# How to create a .db file from .sql

Tags: sqlite

I have a text file with `.sql` extension which contains code for building table and population values into columns.

How would I generate a `.db` sqlite file out of that

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using SQLITE via a command the use the `.read FILENAME` to run the SQL you'd then use the .save FILENAME command to save the database (including the .db extension), alternately before using the .read command you could use .open FILENAME)

e.g. Using the file C:/User/Mike/mysql.sql as :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mydata TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable (mydata) VALUES('Fred'),('Mary'),('Sue'),('Tom');
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Starting a command window and then :-

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.407]
> (c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Mike>SQLITE3
> SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
> Enter ".help" for usage hints.
> Connected to a transient in-memory database.
> Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
> sqlite> .read mysql.sql
> 1|Fred
> 2|Mary
> 3|Sue
> 4|Tom
> sqlite>
> ```

- `.read mysql.sql` being manually input after issuing the SQLITE3 command.

PS .help results in :-

```
sqlite> .help
.auth ON|OFF           Show authorizer callbacks
.backup ?DB? FILE      Backup DB (default "main") to FILE
.bail on|off           Stop after hitting an error.  Default OFF
.binary on|off         Turn binary output on or off.  Default OFF
.cd DIRECTORY          Change the working directory to DIRECTORY
.changes on|off        Show number of rows changed by SQL
.check GLOB            Fail if output since .testcase does not match
.clone NEWDB           Clone data into NEWDB from the existing database
.databases             List names and files of attached databases
.dbinfo ?DB?           Show status information about the database
.dump ?TABLE? ...      Dump the database in an SQL text format
                         If TABLE specified, only dump tables matching
                         LIKE pattern TABLE.
.echo on|off           Turn command echo on or off
.eqp on|off|full       Enable or disable automatic EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
.excel                 Display the output of next command in a spreadsheet
.exit                  Exit this program
.expert                EXPERIMENTAL. Suggest indexes for specified queries
.fullschema ?--indent? Show schema and the content of sqlite_stat tables
.headers on|off        Turn display of headers on or off
.help                  Show this message
.import FILE TABLE     Import data from FILE into TABLE
.imposter INDEX TABLE  Create imposter table TABLE on index INDEX
.indexes ?TABLE?       Show names of all indexes
                         If TABLE specified, only show indexes for tables
                         matching LIKE pattern TABLE.
.limit ?LIMIT? ?VAL?   Display or change the value of an SQLITE_LIMIT
.lint OPTIONS          Report potential schema issues. Options:
                         fkey-indexes     Find missing foreign key indexes
.log FILE|off          Turn logging on or off.  FILE can be stderr/stdout
.mode MODE ?TABLE?     Set output mode where MODE is one of:
                         ascii    Columns/rows delimited by 0x1F and 0x1E
                         csv      Comma-separated values
                         column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
                         html     HTML <table> code
                         insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
                         line     One value per line
                         list     Values delimited by "|"
                         quote    Escape answers as for SQL
                         tabs     Tab-separated values
                         tcl      TCL list elements
.nullvalue STRING      Use STRING in place of NULL values
.once (-e|-x|FILE)     Output for the next SQL command only to FILE
                         or invoke system text editor (-e) or spreadsheet (-x)
                         on the output.
.open ?OPTIONS? ?FILE? Close existing database and reopen FILE
                         The --new option starts with an empty file
.output ?FILE?         Send output to FILE or stdout
.print STRING...       Print literal STRING
.prompt MAIN CONTINUE  Replace the standard prompts
.quit                  Exit this program
.read FILENAME         Execute SQL in FILENAME
.restore ?DB? FILE     Restore content of DB (default "main") from FILE
.save FILE             Write in-memory database into FILE
.scanstats on|off      Turn sqlite3_stmt_scanstatus() metrics on or off
.schema ?PATTERN?      Show the CREATE statements matching PATTERN
                          Add --indent for pretty-printing
.selftest ?--init?     Run tests defined in the SELFTEST table
.separator COL ?ROW?   Change the column separator and optionally the row
                         separator for both the output mode and .import
.sha3sum ?OPTIONS...?  Compute a SHA3 hash of database content
.shell CMD ARGS...     Run CMD ARGS... in a system shell
.show                  Show the current values for various settings
.stats ?on|off?        Show stats or turn stats on or off
.system CMD ARGS...    Run CMD ARGS... in a system shell
.tables ?TABLE?        List names of tables
                         If TABLE specified, only list tables matching
                         LIKE pattern TABLE.
.testcase NAME         Begin redirecting output to 'testcase-out.txt'
.timeout MS            Try opening locked tables for MS milliseconds
.timer on|off          Turn SQL timer on or off
.trace FILE|off        Output each SQL statement as it is run
.vfsinfo ?AUX?         Information about the top-level VFS
.vfslist               List all available VFSes
.vfsname ?AUX?         Print the name of the VFS stack
.width NUM1 NUM2 ...   Set column widths for "column" mode
                         Negative values right-justify
sqlite>
```

### The entire process (less creating the file mysql.sql) :-

```
C:\Users\Mike>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 14E1-AC1D

 Directory of C:\Users\Mike

19/11/2018  11:37 AM    <DIR>          .
19/11/2018  11:37 AM    <DIR>          ..
14/11/2018  07:48 PM    <DIR>          Links
14/11/2018  07:48 PM    <DIR>          Music
19/11/2018  11:26 AM               168 mysql.sql
21/08/2017  06:02 PM    <DIR>          Nero
              10 File(s)         82,031 bytes
              34 Dir(s)  149,798,195,200 bytes free

C:\Users\Mike>SQLITE3
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open mydb.db
sqlite> .read mysql.sql
1|Fred
2|Mary
3|Sue
4|Tom
sqlite>

C:\Users\Mike>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 14E1-AC1D

 Directory of C:\Users\Mike

19/11/2018  11:39 AM    <DIR>          .
19/11/2018  11:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
14/11/2018  07:48 PM    <DIR>          Music
19/11/2018  11:39 AM            12,288 mydb.db
19/11/2018  11:26 AM               168 mysql.sql
21/08/2017  06:02 PM    <DIR>          Nero
              11 File(s)         94,319 bytes
              34 Dir(s)  149,797,101,568 bytes free
```